# PTFE (Teflon) combined with Silicon Polymers

Tags: polymers

I wanted to know if it would be possible to combine basic silicon polymers with PTFE in order to create a stable, non reactive silicon rubber that won't react to butane or other hydrocarbons in particular. Is this doable? If so what would it take to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean as in a copolymer rather than a formulation of the two polymers ?

Comment: Yes I believe as a copolymer. Whichever will be better as I intend to combine the two for use as a flexible chem resistant mold.

Comment: I would suggest looking up "fluorosilicone" polymers, Kalrez plus silanes, then go from there. I suspect the organic portion of the siloxane will always be susceptible to something, just like PDMS or poly(diphenylsiloxane). To prevent this, you may need an alternating TFE /dimethylsiloxane sequence or as good as, rather than a block copolymer. Possibly this suggests a living polymerisation? I couldn't say.